# Do things in $http.then(), and then return promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

```
initUserProfile: function() {

  return $http.get('myapi/user/profil').
  then(function(response) {
    current_user = response.data;
    if (current_user.profilpicture) {
      current_user.profilpicture = $rootScope.baseURL + "/images/users/" + current_user.username + "/" + current_user.profilpicture;
    }
  }, function(err) {
    // log error
  });
};
```

I want this to return a promise, here it's the case but it's the $http success promise.
How can i do to return a promise when the changes inside the then() are completed ?

Comment: `initUserProfile` already returns a promise. So what is your problem?

Comment: you forgot a ' in this line :    return $http.get(**** ' ***myapi/user/profil').

Comment: Anyway, return from the then block if you want to chain promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return `current_user` in `then()` and it will be available as argument of next `then()` in the chain

```
initUserProfile: function() {

  return $http.get('myapi/user/profil').
  then(function(response) {
    current_user = response.data;
    if (current_user.profilpicture) {
      current_user.profilpicture = $rootScope.baseURL + "/images/users/" + current_user.username + "/" + current_user.profilpicture;
    }

     return current_user;


  }).catch(function(err) {
    // log error
  });
};
```

In controller:

```
myService.initUserProfile().then(function(current_user){
    $scope.user = current_user;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    initUserProfile: function ()
    {

    var defer=$q.defer();

    $http.get('myapi/user/profil').
            then(function (response) {
            current_user = response.data;
                    if (current_user.profilpicture)
                    {
                        current_user.profilpicture = $rootScope.baseURL + "/images/students/" + current_user.username + "/" + current_user.profilpicture;

                    //here resolve
                    defer.resolve();

                    }else{
                     defer.reject();
                    }


                }, function (err) {
                    // log error
                    defer.reject();
                });


    //retun promise
    return defer.promise;
    };
```

Comment: This is considered an anti pattern...no need for $q here at all

Comment: question is how to return promise when code in then is completed - so this is answer. why anti pattern, if we need method to be resolved after some asynchronous code.

Comment: because `$http` already returns a promise... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: i know that, but question was to get promise after code in then, not promise from http i think author knows that http returns promise. I should not have had minus for that answer. Using $q if we can use promise from http has no sense, but use $q after some code or in if has sense.

Comment: don't think you understand that when you return inside then() a promise is passed down chain. You didn't resolve with any data either so controller won't get anything